# How to print a bash history command and append it to a file?

Tags: bash

You can print a command with:

```
!2500:p
```

But how do I append that command to a file? I thought:

```
!2500:p >> .bashrc
```

But that just prints everything including the ">> .bashrc" to stdout.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`!` repeats the numbered command, so you need to echo it. Use the `:q` modifier to quote the history substitution properly.

```
echo !2500:q >> .bashrc
```

Comment: Thanks, that works, but how do I preserve quotes and special characters. E.g. ls -al | grep "[[:space:]]\."

Comment: That's a bit more tricky

Comment: You need to add the `:q` modifier to quote it properly: `echo !2500:q >> .bashrc`